# "too many values to unpack" iterating over dictionary indexed by tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to define a function that Returns a list of the data elements from the keys of the dictionary studentPerf (very large but I've given the first three items of) relating to a specified index, where each possible value is listed only once. For example, if the keys in the dictionary were [(‘John’,2),(‘Julie’,2),(‘John’,3),(‘John’,1),(‘Julie’,1),(‘Julie’,3)], then this function should return [‘John’,’Julie’] for index 0, and [1,2,3] for index 1.

So far I've been receiving the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

```
studentPerf = {('Jeffery','male','junior'):[0.81,0.75,0.74,0.8],
('Able','male','senior'):[0.87,0.79,0.81,0.81],
('Don','male','junior'):[0.82,0.77,0.8,0.8]}


def select(key, index): 
    for key, index in studentPerf.keys():
        print(index)

select(0,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your purpose.

But function select's error is:

1. The studentPerf.keys() return a iterable with 3-tuple
2. your code `for key, index in` just unpack two item

you should:

1. `for index0, index1, index2 in studentPerf.keys():` or
2. `for key, *index in studentPerf.keys()`. this way the index would be a 2-tuple

Comment: thank you, this is for an exercise in my python class where I need to have 2 arguments in the function I create.  I used your second example but now no matter what arguments I pass into the select() function I get the same output. Ths is returned:
    ['male', 'junior']
    ['male', 'senior']
    ['male', 'junior']
 I want the first argument to select which key in the dictionary to select from, and the second argument to select which element in that tuple to choose.

Answer (score 0):

For unpacking the tuple (key here..) You have 3 values. But, you're only unpacking into two vars. So do:

```
for (name, gender, year)
```

Comment: I purposefully used .keys(), as I'm not interested in the values in my dictionary.  Essentially I want to take different parts of the tuple. This way I can sort through the dictionary by gender and class using the select() function